# How to play Bluetooth speaker and device speaker at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, music, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I'm on the Moto z and on 7.1.1 nougat. I have the JBL speaker mod and a Bluetooth speaker. But I want to use them both. How do I do that? If I connect to the speaker the mod speaker turns off.